# How to create Html.ActionLink for Current URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3.2, I am trying to create an Html ActionLink for the current URL like in the Bootstrap example here:

https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_breadcrumbs.cfm

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
<li class="active">Pears</li>
</ul>
```

Microsoft has a lot of information on their page for ActionLink

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

There doesn't seem to be a version for creating the active list item unless I am missing something in those overloads.

So, how would I create an ActionLink for "Pears" in the unordered list above (no hyperlink and class="active")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

> If you don't want a hyperlink, don't use the ActionLink

I still used an ActionLink for Home and for Fruit, but Pears just got the standard `<li>` treatment like below:

```cs
public static string BuildBreadcrumbNavigation(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    var controllerName = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    // optional condition: I didn't wanted it to show on home and account controller
    if ((controllerName != "Home") && (controllerName != "Account"))
    {
        var homeLink = helper.ActionLink(
            linkText: "Home",
            actionName: "Index",
            controllerName: "Home").ToHtmlString();
        var sb = new StringBuilder($"<ol class='breadcrumb'><li>{homeLink}</li>");

        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        var urlParts = url.Split(new char[] { '/' });

        if (!urlParts.Contains("Console"))
        {
            var controllerLink = helper.ActionLink(
                linkText: controllerName.SplitTitleWords(),
                actionName: "Index",
                controllerName: controllerName);
            sb.Append($"<li>{controllerLink}</li>");
        } else
        {
            var a = $"<a href=\"{url}\">Console</a>";
            sb.Append($"<li>{a}</li>");
        }

        var actionName = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        sb.Append($"<li class=\"active\">{actionName.SplitTitleWords()}</li>");

        result = sb.Append("</ol>").ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**SplitTitleWords** is a custom extension that I wrote to break-up words such as `AddPDFResource` into `Add PDF Resource`.

```cs
public static string SplitTitleWords(this string value)
{
    var cList = new List<char>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        cList.Add(value[0]); // just add the first letter, whether caps, no caps, or number
        for (var i = 1; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = value[i];
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
            {   //                                01234567891234    0123456789012345  
                // check special cases like class AddPDFResource => Add PDF Resource
                var c0 = value[i - 1];
                if (char.IsUpper(c0))
                {
                    if (i + 1 < value.Length)
                    {
                        var c1 = value[i + 1];
                        if (!char.IsUpper(c1))
                        {
                            cList.Add(' ');
                        }
                    }
                } else
                {
                    cList.Add(' ');
                }
            }
            cList.Add(c);
        }
    }
    var result = new String(cList.ToArray());
    return result;
}
```